# "I haven't received the confirmation letter via/by/from email"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I was booking a trip and I was supposed to get an email that confirms my booking but I didn't get it so I was asking a customer service representative about the reason. I was wondering which preposition I should go with?

> "I haven't received the confirmation letter via/by/from email"

Also are there any other ways to say this?

Comment: *Via* definitely works, but better still: "I haven't received the confirmation email"

Comment: "from" is incorrect. The other two are correct. "By" is the more natural of the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most natural ways to say this generally avoid propositions. You can refer to the confirmation you are expecting as a *confirmation email* or an *email confirmation*.

> I haven't received the [**email confirmation**]/[**confirmation email**] for my booking.

You can also refer to *an email containing my confirmation*.

> I've just made a booking and I've been expecting **an email containing my confirmation**, but it hasn't arrived

Phrases with prepositions can also be used, but usually in contexts where the *delivery method* is the key issue, for example

> I was expecting a confirmation to have been sent to me **via email**, but I received an SMS 
> Could I have the confirmation sent **in an email**?

In these cases, the most natural prepositions are *in* (general), *by* (neutral; buisness-like), *via* (more formal [in the US]).

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence, whether it uses "via", "by" or "from", draws attention to the *means of communication*, when what is important is that you haven't received the confirmation.

Juhasz's suggestion is good. Or you could simply say,

> I haven't received the confirmation.